# Drop rows with no values after checking all columns in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below.
I would like to check all columns and delete rows if no values.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `dropna`

```
df = df.dropna(how = 'all')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.dropna()
```

[Check the Pandas Docs here for more info](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dropna()` function for your dataframe.

```py
df.dropna(axis=0, how="all")
```

`axis=0` performs deletion on rows
`how="all"` deletes the rows if all the columns for that row are empty. Use `" any"` if you want the row to be deleted in case of any missing column. You can also use the `thresh=<int>` parameter to delete the row if the number of missing values exceeds the threshold.